# How to make WebView scrollable in react-native-webview?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-paper

I have `<WebView>` that is embedded in a `<Card.Content>` as I am using `react-native-paper`. I am trying to have `WebView` scrollable. The webview shows but not scrollable.

Code I am using:

```
  <Card theme={{ roundness: 20 }} style={{ margin: 10, height: height*0.8 }} elevation={14}>
     <Card.Content style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <WebView
              style={{ width: width * 0.8, height: height * 0.9 }}
              allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures={false}
              source={{ uri: "https://paypal.com"}}
              pullToRefreshEnabled={false}
              javaScriptEnabled
              startInLoadingState
              decelerationRate="normal"
              scalesPageToFit={Platform.OS == "android"?  false : true}
              originWhitelist={['*']}
              domStorageEnabled={true}
              scrollEnabled
              renderError={e => { console.log(e); }}
              />
        </View>
     </Card.Content>
  </Card>
```

How can I make `WebView` scrollable?

Answer (score 9):

Just add `nestedScrollEnabled=true` props i webview component

```
<ScrollView
    <WebView nestedScrollEnabled source={{uri:'https://www.website.com' }} />
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try to wrap your `WebView` inside a `ScrollView` like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/22'
          }}
          style={{ height: 100 }}
        />

        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://bbc.co.uk/news' }}
          style={{ height: 100 }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can use [react-native-autoheight-webview](https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview)

Comment: can you please explain why you are using two webviews in scrollview? I did not get it.

Comment: I tried your method but did not work. I will give a try the library you mentioned.

Comment: I added two webviews just for testing!

Comment: I found the issue thank you for helping, the issue was that I was using margin on `<Card>` view. I removed the margin and I got it scrollable now. Not sure why margin affected the `<WebView>` scrolling.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this issue.

#### Problem definition

`Webview` was inside `ScrollView` and `Webview` was taking height greater than `ScrollView` thats why the `ScrollView` was stealing the `scroll` event and I was not able to scroll through the webpage.

#### Solution

Make `Webview` fit the `Scrollview` height. For this we need to use `flexGrow` in `contentContainerStyle`

###### Simple Example

```
   return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      >
        <WebView source={{ uri: contentUrl }} originWhitelist={['*']} />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

`{flex: 1}` and `{ width: '100%' }` are important otherwise content will not be visible.

Comment: Thank you for the width 100%. How is some software this dumb?